# Not printing series of variable in golang

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang got some weird output using go v1.18
when I print `firstName, lastName, birthday, created` only got result as `created`
I have printed declaring variable and printing whole thing again it works fine
the problem is with `var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

func main() {
    firstName := getUserData("Enter First Name: ")
    lastName := getUserData("Enter Last Name: ")
    birthdate := getUserData("Enter Date of Birth: ")
    created := time.Now()

    fmt.Println(firstName, lastName, birthdate, created) //only prints created
    fmt.Println(firstName) // prints firstName
    fmt.Println(lastName) // prints lastName
    fmt.Println(birthdate) // prints birthdate
    fmt.Println(created) // prints created
}

func getUserData(promptText string) string {
    fmt.Print(promptText)
    userInput, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    cleanedInput := strings.Replace(userInput, "\n", "", -1)
    return cleanedInput
}
```

Comment: I would suggest checking the error result of `reader.ReadString` and logging it if it is not nil. I suspect this error will give you more information on why the bug is happening.

Comment: Also, I might suggest the using `fmt` package `Scanf` or `Scanln` functions rather than `ReadString`.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Managed to print all of the properties

Comment: i was able to print the below
`fmt.Println(firstName) // prints firstName
    fmt.Println(lastName) // prints lastName
    fmt.Println(birthdate) // prints birthdate
    fmt.Println(created)`

but not able to print the following
`fmt.Println(firstName, lastName, birthdate, created)`

Comment: `Scanf` and `Scanln` expect space separated values.  Some names have spaces.

Comment: ok i used `fmt.scanln(&variable)` this works fine now is there any downside of using `bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)` or `fmt.scanln(&variable)`

Comment: @hisam I think this will only happen in windows not in linux

Comment: @SiddheshNayak the fmt package will handle the return or Carriage return for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `strings.TrimSpace` instead of `strings.Replace`
because in your code you did not remove the Carriage return `\r`

See the corrected code below.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

func main() {
    firstName := getUserData("Enter First Name: ")
    lastName := getUserData("Enter Last Name: ")
    birthdate := getUserData("Enter Date of Birth: ")
    created := time.Now()

    fmt.Println(firstName, lastName, birthdate, created) //will print all
    fmt.Println(firstName)                               // prints firstName
    fmt.Println(lastName)                                // prints lastName
    fmt.Println(birthdate)                               // prints birthdate
    fmt.Println(created)                                 // prints created
}

func getUserData(promptText string) string {
    fmt.Print(promptText)
    userInput, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    cleanedInput := strings.TrimSpace(userInput)

    return cleanedInput
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked instead of replacing with \n used \r as you said

Comment: you are wlc, it is better to use debug to check the exact value of  the variables that's how I find the solution

Comment: @MSH: To check the exact value of `string` variables use `fmt.Printf` with the `%q` verb: `%q a single-quoted character literal safely escaped with Go syntax.`. For example: https://go.dev/play/p/oiayEiQ-tsX